# How to remove html marks from string in rails 1.2.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to clean a string and remove every html mark from it in a rails 1.2.5 application.

I suppose I need something like html_safe but I don't know if there is something like this in that rails version.

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean strip html tags? or are you having issues with escaped html string?

Comment: I have a string like "<p>hello..." and I want to return "hello..."

Comment: use strip_tags (not sure if this already available in 1.2.5)

Comment: That worked perfect, set it as an answer to mark it as solved please ;)

Comment: done. it's nice to know that it's already defined in 1.2.5. interesting that you're still trying to use that rails version :)

Comment: It's just for an old app in production :( But it still works ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use strip_tags to remove html tags from a string

```
>> strip_tags('<p>hello</p>') # 'hello'
```